# I can't load images from Flamelink that is integrated with Firebase and Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, flamelink-cms

Right now, the code is working for all the strings I passed however, I can't retrieve my images from storage and see the fieldId needed. I followed the documentation of flamelink-js-sdk but it doesn't seem to clarify what should be done for images.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
async created() {
app.content
  .get({
    schemaKey: "teamPage",
    populate: [
      {
        field: "title"
      },
      {
        field: "description"
      },
      {
        field: "executiveBoard",
        fields: [
          "title",
          "position",
          "image",
          "facebook",
          "github",
          "linkedin"
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
  .then(teamPage => {
    this.teamPage = teamPage;
    console.log(this.teamPage.executiveBoard[0].image);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));},
```

Here's where I render them

```
 <team-circle
        v-for="board in teamPage.executiveBoard"
        :key="board.title"
        class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4"
        :name="board.title"
        :image="board.image"
        :facebook="board.facebook"
        :linkedin="board.linkedin"
        :github="board.github"
      >{{ board.position }}</team-circle>
```

[Check this link to see what data is passed in the src of the img tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg3HU.png)

Thank you again. Hope you can help me out on this!

Comment: please don't post images of code, you rather need to include that code in text format to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```js
app.content
  .get({
    schemaKey: "teamPage",
    populate: [
      {
        field: "title"
      },
      {
        field: "description"
      },
      {
        field: "executiveBoard",
        fields: [
          "title",
          "position",
          "image",
          "facebook",
          "github",
          "linkedin"
        ],
        populate: ["image"]
      }
    ]
  })
```

note the `populate: ["image"]` addition (see [this](https://flamelink.github.io/flamelink-js-sdk/#/content?id=get-examples))

`this.teamPage.executiveBoard[0].image` will now be an array of objects example

```js
[{ 
  contentType: "image/png",
  id: "xxx",
  ...
  url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/....."
}]
```

you can then access the url for example like this

```js
this.teamPage.executiveBoard[0].image[0].url
```